How to get working dependencies in jupyter notebook/lab using rise (reveal.js) + ipycanvas + ipywidgets
I simple run this code in a jupyter notebook/lab cell:
from ipycanvas import Canvas
from ipywidgets import Button
from IPython.display import display

WIDTH = 200  # px
HEIGHT = 200  # px

# Create a canvas 700x250 pixels with a black border
canvas = Canvas(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)

# Add black border around the canvas
canvas.stroke_style = 'black'
canvas.stroke_rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

# List to store clicked positions
clicked_positions = []

# Function to handle clicks and draw red dots
def handle_click(x, y):
    # Add the clicked position to the list
    clicked_positions.append((x, y))
    # Draw a red dot with radius 3 at the clicked position
    canvas.fill_style = 'red'
    canvas.fill_circle(x, y, 3)

# Attach the click event handler to the canvas
canvas.on_mouse_down(lambda x, y: handle_click(x, y))

# Button to display clicked positions
show_button = Button(description="Show clicked positions")

# Function to display the clicked positions
def show_positions(b):
    print("Clicked positions:", clicked_positions)

show_button.on_click(show_positions)

# Display the canvas and button
display(canvas, show_button)

IT WORKS!
Now I want to run it in a reveal.js/jupyterlab_rise/rise slideshow
And this is where all the madness starts, so I won't put any of the dozens of issues I experienced in here.
I will just state, that the best outcome, of actually seeing and being able to click onto the canvas within the presentation I only had when installing:
python3.12 -m pip install notebook==6.5.4 ipywidgets==8.1.5 ipycanvas==0.11.0 rise==5.7.1
So in the end it looks like this:
>> python3.12 -m jupyter --version

Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.10.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.5
ipywidgets       : 8.1.5
jupyter_client   : 8.6.2
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.2
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.10.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.4
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.9.0

But also this version crashs after setting a few dots onto the canvas.
ANY HELP is greatly appreciated!
Meaning: - I need a canvas, which I can draw on to retrieve the coordinates to the next cell AND I want to do it inside a reveal.js - presentation using jupyter.
If someone has a working version of jupyter notebook/lab using ipywidgets + reaveal.js and could document its version this would be super helpful, since I already tested a lot of combinations without success -> especially version 4.x.x seem to break a lot of extension codes?! I also wouldn't know for which jupyter version the extension developer created its release eg. ipywidgets?!?

I worry you are possibly exacerbating your issues by using the latest Python (3.12) and old tech like Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4. For ipycanvas, ipywidgets version 8 support only got added two days ago, I think. See here. There's probably still some rough edges there. Similarly, when I search ipywidgets in the ipycanvas code, there's a lot of examples specifying ...

 8, see here. You also need to worry about clashes, like this example with all three techs targeting complex in-browser things. Thinking of ways to possibly simplfy, there's no way to simiulate the thing you need ipycanvas for with ipywidgets and matplotlib? You can click on things and get coordinates with matplotlib but I don't know how well the interactive feature of matplotlib works along with RISE at the moment.
